# Getting a checkbox to write a JavaScript cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, checkbox, setcookie

I've got a page with a splash screen, where users select one of two languages in which the rest of the site will be displayed. Next to each language option is a "remember my choice", HTML form, checkbox. How can I have the selected checkbox write a cookie with the language preference, which would skip the splash screen on future visits?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can use something like below, Note code not tested:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays) {
        var exdate=new Date()
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
        document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate)
    }

    function getCookie(c_name) {
        if (document.cookie.length>0) {
            c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
            if (c_start!=-1) { 
                c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1 
                c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start)
                if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length
                    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end))
            } 
        }
        return null
    }
onload=function(){
document.getElementById('linksNewWindow').checked = getCookie('linksNewWindow')==1? true : false;
}
function set_check(){
setCookie('linksNewWindow', document.getElementById('linksNewWindow').checked? 1 : 0, 100);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hi</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="linksNewWindow" onchange="set_check();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great reference for javascript cookies, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html, I suggest doing this with PHP other than javascript simply because I the cookies and session functions are much more powerful with server-side scripting.

> document.cookie
>   
> ^ this is the js code that represents a pages cookies.